# BigQuery Crashlytics - Crash free users / sessions

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics, looker-studio, firebase-crash-reporting

I've linked my firebase crashlytics data to bigquery and setup the data studio templates provided by google. A lot of great data in there except the most important metrics required for my dashboard: **crash free users** and **crash free sessions** as a percentage.

Nothing stands out in the schema which I could be used to calculate this.

Any ideas how I might get this value? It's displayed in the firebase dashboard so it must be available..

[image]

Comment: do you know if there's a sample shared table to write queries from

Comment: @FelipeHoffa there's a sample datastudio report but I don't think you can write queries on the underlying data https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/10TMAKxL0ZxcNGTLDQy1LAF5V7uNDYxRC/page/1xZU/preview

Answer (score 11):

I looked into the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?ref_topic=7029512) and found `event_name='app_exception'`. With that you can write a query like

```sql
WITH userCrashes AS (
  SELECT user_pseudo_id, MAX(event_name = 'app_exception') hasCrash 
  FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003` 
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT
  IF(hasCrash,'crashed','crash-free') crashState,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users,
  ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)) OVER (),2) AS userShare
FROM userCrashes
GROUP BY 1
```

But there is also a flag 'fatal' in the event parameters. In the example data, it's always true, but in case you wanted to take it into respect, you could do something like

```sql
WITH userCrashes AS (
  SELECT 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    MAX(event_name = 'app_exception') hasCrash,
    MAX(event_name = 'app_exception' 
      AND (select value.int_value=1 from unnest(event_params) where key='fatal')
    ) hasFatalCrash
  FROM `firebase-public-project.analytics_153293282.events_20181003` 
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT
  IF(hasCrash,'crashed','crash-free') crashState,
  IF(hasFatalCrash,'crashed fatal','crash-free') fatalCrashState,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS users,
  ROUND(COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) / SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id)) OVER (),2) AS userShare
FROM userCrashes
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Disclaimer: I never worked with firebase, so this is all just based on documentation and example data. Hope it helps, though.

Comment: As per my understanding, this will be helpful to see the result by ruining this query in google cloud platform Query Editor. Can anyone help me on how this data can be added in Google data studio dashboard ?

Comment: Very help, Martin! I'm struggling to put something together for per-day, as seen in Crashlytics so I can graph it. How could I do that with your query? I'd like to do this because its not possible to have crash-free per platform (ios/android) overlay over x days. Would also take just a replication of the graph in crashlytics. Thanks!

Comment: So what is the output of the query? I think it's not crash-free-sessions.