# Calculate crash free sessions based on analytics and crashlytics data (BigQuery)

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, crashlytics

Assuming the following definitions are in place:

1. *The crash free sessions* number is the percentage of sessions in the specified time range not ended by a crash of the application.
2. *The crash free users* is the percentage of distinct users who did not experience a crash during the specified time period.

Is it possible to calculate p1 of the above using analytical data exports into BigQuery? Closest thing I was able to find is this ticket on SO [BigQuery Crashlytics - Crash free users / sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54578347/bigquery-crashlytics-crash-free-users-sessions) but I think what it actually does is calculating p2 and not p1. To rephrase my question, how to identify user sessions and link them with crash experiences if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took some of the information from these [BigQuery examples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/bigquery/basic-queries) to obtain and aggregate the info to get the overall sessions and the sessions with 'app_exception' events. From this you could calculate the percentage of crash free sessions:

```sql
SELECT
  SUM(sessions) as sessions,
  SUM(app_exception) as session_with_crash,
  1 - (SUM(app_exception) / SUM(sessions)) as crash_free_sessions
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    COUNT(user_pseudo_id) as sessions,
    SUM(IF (event_name = 'app_exception', 1, 0))  as app_exception,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS ga_session_id
  FROM `Firebase_project_name.analytics_property_name.events_*` 
  -- WHERE event_name = 'app_exception'
  GROUP BY ga_session_id
)
```

This is the result I got:

| sessions | sessions_with_crash | crash_free_sessions |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 282083 | 94 | 0.9996667 |

Keep in mind that in the above query all the data is being queried so make sure to adjust the required timeframe.

Comment: I've just tested it and it works for me, though ain't cheap :)  
Thank you for the answer, I've never seeing anything similar!